# Grid view not displaying on click of a button in listview

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have a list view which displays the list of data from database and have provided with a button in each row on click of which the id is retrieved at the back end using command argument and data of the respective id is displayed in the grid view.
The code is as follows:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lstvwResultInquiry" runat="server" DataKeyNames="inquiry_id" 
         onitemdatabound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" 
         onpagepropertieschanging="PagePropertiesChanging" 
         onitemcanceling="CancelListViewItem" onitemediting="EditListViewItem" 
         onselectedindexchanging="lstvwResultInquiry_SelectedIndexChanging" >
             <LayoutTemplate >
             <div id="rightnowIn">
                                <table  class="gridview"  cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" >

                                    <tr class="header">                                                               
                                         <th width="140">Company</th>
                                        <th width="220">Event</th>
                                        <th width="125">Country</th>
                                        <th width="125">Date</th>
                                        <th width="100">Details</th>                                                                                                                   
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                          <tr id="Tr1"  runat="server" align="center" >
                          <td colspan="2" align="left"><asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td id="Td1"  runat="server" style="" colspan="4">
                      <asp:DataPager class="mpart" ID="DataPager1" PageSize="10" runat="server" align="center">
                            <Fields>                              
                                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonType="Link"  ButtonCount="3" PreviousPageText="<<<" NextPageText=">>>" />     
                            </Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>    
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left"></td>
                </tr>
                                </table>
                                </div>
                            </LayoutTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate >
                                <tr class="itemTemplateTr" >

                                    <td style="color: #403f3f; font-weight: bold;"><%# Eval("company")%></td>
                                        <td><asp:Label  ID="lblEvents" runat="server" ></asp:Label></td>
                                         <td><%# Eval("country_name")%></td>
                                         <td><%# Eval("date", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%></td>
                                           <%   if (Session["session_log_id"] != null)
                                { %>
                                       <%--<td class="command"><asp:HyperLink ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="View" OnClientClick="javascript: show_popup()"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("inquiry_id")%>' CommandName="view"   cssclass="linkEditButton"  Font-Underline="True"  /></td>--%>
                                   <td> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="view" OnClientClick="javascript: show_popup()" CommandName="view" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("inquiry_id")%>' OnClick="buttonClick"/>  </td>            

                                 <%} %>

                                  <td>
                                            <asp:Button ID="buttReminder"  runat="server" Text="view"  Visible="false" CssClass="reminderButton"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("inquiry_id")%>' OnClick="buttReminderInquiry_Click"   BorderStyle="None" /></td>


                                </tr> 
                            </ItemTemplate>           
                      <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                     <tr class="alternatingItem">                      

                                      <td style="color: #403f3f; font-weight: bold;"><%# Eval("company")%></td>
                                     <td><asp:Label  ID="lblEvents" runat="server"  ></asp:Label></td>
                                         <td><%# Eval("country_name")%></td>
                                         <td><%# Eval("date", "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%></td>
                                          <%   if (Session["session_log_id"] != null)
                                { %>
                                       <%--<td class="command"><asp:HyperLink ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="View" OnClientClick="javascript: show_popup()"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("inquiry_id")%>' cssclass="linkEditButton"  Font-Underline="True"  /></td>      --%>
                        <td> <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="view" CommandName="view" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("inquiry_id")%>' OnClick="buttonClick" OnClientClick="javascript: show_popup()" /></td>

                                <%}   %> 

                                 <td>
                                            <asp:Button ID="buttReminder"  runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="reminderButton"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("inquiry_id")%>' OnClientClick="javascript: show_div()"   BorderStyle="None" /></td>     

                                </tr>

                      </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                      <EmptyDataTemplate>
                      <div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold">0 Results Founds</div> 
                      </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

code on click of view button is as follows which binds the data for grid view but data is not displayed in grid view:

```
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string CommandName = btn.CommandName;
    string inquiryID = btn.CommandArgument;
     id = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument.ToString());             
     this.BindGrid();
```

But if i try the same code with some other button than it works.It do not work with the list view button click..please help

Answer (score 0):

Button click is not working because buttons that are created dynamically do not have click event associated with them. Do somethig like this.

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
string CommandName = btn.CommandName;
string inquiryID = btn.CommandArgument;
id = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument.ToString()); 
btn.Click += btn_Click;
```

and "btn.Click += btn_Click;" this line for event handling. & write binding code in it

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //binding code goes here
}
```

Try something like this (NOT TESTED)

```
AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = btn.UniqueID;
trigger.EventName = "Click";
yourUpdPanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

`ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
        if (scriptManager != null) {
            scriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btn);
        }`

Comment: Grid view is visible on second click..on first click it do not display any data.what could be the problem?

Comment: you used Page.IsPostBack() on page_load or not? try using it

Comment: my list view is inside the update panel content template. will that affect the code?

Comment: You'll have to register click event of button update panels trigger.
I've updated my answer. please check it. But it's not tested.

Comment: i pasted the code i am getting error at last line i.e
 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(System.Web.UI.Control)'

Comment: ok. i did the same but still its not working.Anyways thank you